# What's the quickest way to do complex queries on Twitter using their Ruby API?

Tags: ruby, twitter

I want to create a complex query, e.g. return the first 100 Twitter Users that match the following criteria:

- Have greater than X # of followers
- Have greater than X # of tweets
- Have the string "Rails developer" or "Rails" in their bio
- Have tweeted in the last X days.

I was looking through their API docs and it seems so complex to just get something up and running quickly. I don't want to create a full blown app, I just want something simple that will help me do some research.

Am I overthinking this and it should be easy to do via their API (Ruby preferably) ?

I also don't mind it being run locally, and spitting out a text file or a csv file - but also if there is a nice way to have it spit out a nicely formatted HTML page that would be good too.

I just want to get at the data, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be using the [GET users/search](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/search) API method. You can search on "rails" and page through the results discarding any users who don't match your followers/status requirements. It isn't going to be perfect but in general Twitter tries to return popular/relevant users first.